# How can I draw texts within a cartesian coordinate system with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am new to Ti*k*Z and was wondering how to draw a simple figure as given below.

[image: sample image]

Comment: do you have the data? If yes please paste it in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could

- use `pgfplots` for drawing coordinate system with grid, axis and ticks with labels, without drawing any plot
- place the text as nodes via `axis cs` coordinates
- use styles for font type and size

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize}]
  \begin{axis}[
      axis y line     = left,
      axis x line     = bottom,
      xtick           = {-37,-36,...,-29},
      ytick           = {9,9.5,...,14},
      ticklabel style = {font = \sffamily\footnotesize},
      grid,
      grid style = {color=gray!50, dotted},
      xmin       = -38,   xmax = -28,
      ymin       = 9,     ymax = 14,
    ]      
    \node at (axis cs:-34,10)   {companies};
    \node at (axis cs:-32,12)   {institutions};
    \node at (axis cs:-34,13.4) {Agency};
    \node at (axis cs:-37,13)   {schools};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Just a small addendum (that you probably know of): With `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or newer), `axis cs` is the default coordinate system for `node`s etc. inside an `axis`, so then one doesn't have to write `axis cs:` in all the coordinates.

Answer (score 8):

A bit like [Stefan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261614) but with (some of) the data in a table:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread{%
x     y     label        
-37   13.25 school       
-34   13.25 Agency       
-33   14.00 body         
-34   12.50 organisation 
-34.5 12.00 organizations
-32    9.50 industry     
-34   10.00 companies    
-30   14.00 office       
-34.5 12.75 agencies     
-36.5 11.75 Association
-35.5 9.5   society 
}\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis y line=left, axis x line=bottom,
  xmin=-38, xmax=-27, ymin=9, ymax=14.5,
  every node near coord/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\addplot [only marks, nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic] 
  table [x=x, y=y, meta=label] {\data};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]